# How can I get plusone to display my images?

Tags: google-plus-one

I just put an google plusone button on my site. If I `+1` the page and then go to my google+ account and look at my `+1`'s it shows up, but it has no picture.

So my question, are there any tips to get `+1` do display the information I want it to display, especially my logo?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the standard image_src:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://blah-blah.com/blah.jpg" />
```

Haven't tried it but I found it in this discussion: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=487a1a88078bbf62&hl=en

Good luck :)

Comment: Seems to be some problem with the +1 button, but google are on it! :) Gonna keep an eye on the link you posted, thank you verry much!